# How does it harm if I install JDK on my ubuntu server when JRE is just enough for me?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, java

I just need JRE for my programs. But how does it harm if I use JDK when JRE is enough for my webserver? Does it only mean more harddisk space for JDK & except for that, no other waste?

*I use Ubuntu Server Edition & want to use a PPA but that only provides JDK not JRE alone thus I am forced either to choose JDK or avoid PPA installation.*

Answer (score 1):

It means you have a huge amount of code compared to just the JRE. Generally speaking. JAVA's JRE doesn't have a wonderful track record in terms of security holes... The JDK is like multiplying that by three.

If you can deal with:

1. Higher threat of compromise
2. More space used
3. More bandwidth on update day

You can run the JDK. General Linux principles involve something called **KISS** (Keep it Simple....-Silly-...). Installing the JDK when you only need the JRE isn't going to cause the Linux Server Police to show up at your house, arrest you, and kick your puppy... The old hats.. will just kinda sit back.. and sigh uneasily.

We recommend that you use the JRE and not the full JDK if possible... But.. risk assessment is something you (or someone you know) will have to be responsible for.